# PHP: use a database within a class

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, pdo

I already have a database file that connects to a database when I include it

**class-database.php**

```
class dbFactory {
    private static $host    = 'some.host.com';
    private static $name    = 'someDB';
    private static $user    = 'someUser';
    private static $pass    = 'somePassword';


    public function __construct() { }


    public static function pdo() {
        try {
            # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
            return new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$name", $user, $pass);
            }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return null;
            exit;
            }  
    } // End: pdo()
} //End class
```

I usually access this by:

```
require( 'some-file-path' . 'class-database.php' );
$db = dbFactory::pdo();
```

Here is the question:
**How can I access `$db` from within another class?**

For instance, if I have a class file called `class-html.php` and **within that class** (AKA, as part of the class code) I need something like...:

**class-html.php**

```
class html {
  ...some code...
  $db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_head');
  ...some more code...
} //End: html
```

What I've been doing without success is:

```
require( 'some-file-path' . 'class-database.php' );
$db = dbFactory::pdo();

require( 'some-file-path' . 'class-html.php' );
```

I am getting error messages and am not sure what to do from here

Comment: In this case, both answers are what I need to resolve my problem. However, this site does not allows to accept two entries as the answers. What should I to?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Singleton class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

```
class dbFactory {

    //...
    private static $pdo_instance = null;

    private static function getPDOinstance() {
        if (self::$pdo_instance === null) {
            try {
                self::$pdo_instance = new PDO("...");
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                //...
            }
        }
        return self::$pdo_instance;
    }

}
```

When you now access `dbFactory::getPDOinstance()` you'll only have one PDO instance of creating new ones inside each class using the DB

Answer (score 1):

Your class inside `class-html.php` can be modified a bit, along the following lines:

```
require( 'some-file-path' . 'class-database.php' );

class SomeClass {
  public $db;

  def __construct() {
    $db = dbFactory::getPDOinstance();
    // existing code ..
  }

  // other code      
}
```

Then, you can require the class as usual and:

```
require( 'some-file-path' . 'class-html.php' );
$obj = new SomeClass();
$obj->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_head')
```

**UPDATE**: This will create a new PDO instance if you instantiate `SomeClass` more than once.
**UPDATE**: Made use of kingkero's answer to use existing `dbFactory` instance, instead.

Comment: One may not want to create a new PDO object for every `SomeClass` object, nor for such objects to differ from those used elsewhere.

Comment: @stoic If an instance of a database initiated already, in this case `$db`, this "instance" cannot be accessed within another class (html) and that other class (html) has to create a whole new database instance? Am I correct?

Comment: No, you can "save" the instance inside your dbFactory. You can read more about that in the [wiki link I posted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: @Omar: Yeah, if you have an active instance of `$db`, then it will be different than the one that the above solution creates for you, i.e. the database instance is created, again. If you prefer (and you should) to use a single instance of `$db` make `dbFactory` a singleton class, as kingkero has done in his answer, and then use my method to call the appropriate behaviour. I will update my answer to build upon kingkero's answer.

Comment: @stoic Does it matters that SomeCalss's $db is public? Can it be private or protected or it really does not matters?

Comment: If you want to access `$db` as `$obj->db->query` in your php code outside your class definition, then it needs to be `public`. Otherwise, if you only want to use `$db` inside the `SomeClass` class, then you can make it `private` or `protected` and refer to it as `$this->db` inside the `SomeClass` class. I hope that helps :)